# ubuntu crash after bios battery changed

Tags: grub2, lubuntu

I am trying to repair a JVC netbook for a friend of mine. The problem initially was a bios battery problem which I fixed with a battery change (CR2032 old battery voltage was 0.15V and new one is 3.3 V). After this I booted up the machine and I get the grub menu. I am a noob with Linux stuff but tried any way to figure out whats happening. So on selecting the Ubuntu default (Lubutnu distro) the machine freezes. I then check the other options for booting and get the detailed picture and notice that I get the kernel_thread_helper+0x6/0x10 error with a hex dump and the info stating that my cpu is stalling. This makes me think that it a cpu hardware problem but not sure.

I tried 2 things after this after reading several forums with respect to the kernel_thread_helper error shown below.

1. USB re install.
   This is a pain as the bios shows a usb boot selection but it never boots up. On forums it was suggested to try to boot thru grub but then I can never find the root command or the find command at the grub prompt (after hitting key "c" on the grub option screen). I don't know where to go from here.
2. Change the acpi setting to off on the Linux line in the grub startup (after hitting key "e" on the grub option screen) according to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1591381&p=9943683#post9943683 . I hit Ctrl-x and was then able to get to the prompt (here is where I find it is a lubuntu distro as the prompt tells me that). I tried running startx or lxde but they show up as errors. Do I need to login? Or any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you replace battery the bios settings go back to default.
You should update your BIOS to latest version and set all your settings to improve your situation.

Comment: you mean to flash the bios right? I'm quite reluctant to try that without my friends approval. Let me ask him and find out tomorrow.

Comment: I tried the acpi=off setting in grub. I am able to get to the root command prompt. I see also in the logs that load fallback graphics devices registered as fail.

Comment: @andrnev explain to your friend why he should know better and update software firmware andotherware.

Comment: no reply yet. Have to hang around for another 24 hours.

Comment: @andrnev why dont you just meet him in person or at least call him if this is important?

Comment: @andrnev do what you can right now which is set all settings as best.Then update your bios anyway and set your settings again.

Comment: Well one reason I want him to answer by mail is so that I have written proof that he is ok with the bios upgrade and the risks involved. Don't want to be sued later you know. In the mean time i also saw an issue with the modem module. The netbook had problems booting up as it used to freeze up at the starting screen. The issue pointed to the modem which after disconnecting happens to boot properly except of course the graphics problem stated above. I am eager to try the bios upgrade.i did not understand your last comment though.

Comment: I meant that you can go to your current bios and make it as best as possible right now by setting settings.